# Is laravel image intervention a good way to compress user uploaded images?

Tags: php, image, laravel, image-compression

I was checking out this laravel library to compress user uploaded images.http://image.intervention.io/

I was wondering if this is a good idea for user uploaded images (for profilepictures)? What if the user uploads a picture with a size of 1400x600 and it will be resized to 200x200? Will it be a stretched out image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will be stretched. You want to try [`fit()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/fit) method:

> Combine cropping and resizing to format image in a smart way. The
>   method will find the best fitting aspect ratio of your given width and
>   height on the current image automatically, cut it out and resize it to
>   the given dimension.

```
// crop the best fitting 1:1 ratio (200x200) and resize to 200x200 pixel
$img->fit(200);
```

Comment: what about dpi of an image? @Alexey Mezenin

Answer (score 4):

Intervention is great for handling just this. Here's a quick code snippet to get you going in the right direction:

```
$resize_to = $this->sizes(); //some arbitrary array

//generate our custom image sizes
foreach ($resize_to as $idx => $width) {
    if ($img = Image::make($file->getRealPath())) {
        $img->resize(width, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        });
        $img->encode($encoding_options);
        $img->save($path);
    }
}
```

In the above we're looping over some array of widths that we want to have images resized to. Pay attention to the `$constraints` that we've declared below. The `aspectRatio()` ensures the image never loses it's aspect ratio. The `->upsize()` prevents images from being upsized and losing the resolution.

What you're asking for - resizing a 1400x600 image to `200x200` is unreasonable.

Instead, you should just resize to one dimension and make sure that your HTML can account for the rest. For example, in the above we only observe `widths`. So we'll assume in your `$this->sizes()` array, one of them is 200. But the image was a different ratio, so it didn't produce a 200x200, it produced a 200x150. Handle that in the HTML by using a flexbox super easily:

```
<div class="flex-box-centered">
   <img class="flex-img" src="..."/>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.flex-box-centered {
    display:flex;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    background:#fff;
}

.flex-img {
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

And here's a [jsfiddle illustrating this concept](https://jsfiddle.net/c1vh9vmu/)

Answer (score 1):

When you have loaded image in `$image` as `Intervention\Image\Image` you can easily do it like this:

```
// $height and $width are your max values
if ($image->width < $image->height) {
    $image->resize(null, $height, true, false);
} else {
    $image->resize($width, null, true, false);
}
```

which will resize your image in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

well, yes it is better option. Since Image Intervention uses Imagick in the background. I would recommend you to use Image Intervention. You can also compress images when you saving them.

```
// open and resize an image file
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);

// save file as jpg with medium quality
$img->save('public/bar.jpg', 60);
```

image quality ranges from 0 (poor quality, small file) to 100 (best quality, big file).

Answer (score 1):

composer require intervention/image

// config/app.php

```
return [
    ......
    $provides => [
        ......
        ......,
        'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'
    ],
    $aliases => [
        .....
        .....,
        'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'
    ]
]
```

/* Controller Code

```
    /*With Image Compression*/

            $image = $request->file('profile_image');
            $fileExtension   = strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension()); 
            $file_name       = sha1(uniqid().$image.uniqid()).'.'.$fileExtension;
            $destinationPath = 'uploads/profile_image/';
                $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
                $img->resize(140, 140, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($destinationPath.$file_name);

    /*End With Image Compression*/
```

Comment: good job thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I get the original picture then I resize to 50% which keeps a better ratio. So it doesn't look bad to the user.

```
$imageDimensions = getimagesize($image);
$width = $imageDimensions[0];
$height = $imageDimensions[1];
$new_width = $imageDimensions[0] * 0.5;
$new_height = ceil($height * ($new_width / $width));
$image = Image::make($image)->resize($new_width, $new_height);
```

I first get the normal dimensions then I make a calculation to resize it properly.